# Calculate the Probability of Combinations

Tags: python, list

I am trying to solve this coding problem with no luck.
The problem is like this:
I need to create a function that receives two arguments.  The first is a list that consists n number of string values. The second argument is the amount of values I want in the returned list. My challenge is to create a new list of lists with the maximum amount of combinations possible with k strings in each list.
I think using an example will best explain this:

```
symbols = ['stop', 'bomb', 'moon']
def create_deck(symbols, k):

create_deck(symbols,2)
```

I expect the function to return:

```
[['stop', 'bomb'], ['stop', 'moon'], ['moon', 'bomb']]
```

which is the maximum amount of combinations while k=2. Meaning two words per list.

I dont have any code to present because the furthest I got is a mathematical equation that represents the solution:

```
nCr = n! / r! * (n - r)!
```

but no code.

Comment: Hint: You need to use two `for` loops.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use itertools.

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) should do the trick:

```py
import itertools
def create_deck(symbols, k):
    return [list(x) for x in itertools.combinations(symbols, k)]
```

Comment: Any idea how to approach this not using itertools?
Thats the challenge

Comment: you have to be more specific. in principle you could use a recursive approach and pass the recursion depth as a parameter.